# Email subject encoding

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to configure my e-mail template (Applications->Development->Email Templates) in Kentico and faced with encoding issue with e-mail subject field.
For example, if the e-mail template subject field contains the following text with the macro:

```
Přijatá objednávka číslo {%HTMLEncode(Order.OrderInvoiceNumber) #%}
```

I receive it as

```
P?ijat? objedn?vka ??slo 3019
```

As you can see, the subject doesn't encoded, however, I see it in Kentico back-end without a question marks. 
I have no idea, how to fix it. Pease help.

Comment: Have you checked the Email Encoding settings in Settings -> System -> Email. Also check this link https://docs.kentico.com/k82/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/configuring-settings-for-sites/settings-system/settings-emails

Comment: @ArunKumar, yes, thank you. Email encoding is set to utf-8 by default. I checked it.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your string into [resources](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/multilingual-websites/setting-up-a-multilingual-user-interface/working-with-resource-strings#Workingwithresourcestrings-Addingyourownstrings) and get via macro, so your subect will look like: `{$ReceivedOrderNumber$}{%HTMLEncode(Order.OrderInvoiceNumber)#%}`

Comment: I can try, but what is the difference? As I see in the raw email, the subject field doesn't contain ?utf-8? prefix following with the text encoded (for example, Subject: P?ijat? objedn?vka ??slo 3021). I assume it should be something like the output of php-code example  '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?='

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I have the question marks instead of extended characters :(